# Regex for max number 100, removing the second dot and restrict maximum digits to 6

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate the value from the input type number. I have done this in this way, but this is pretty dirty

```
const value = ev.target.value
if (value > 100 || (value.length === 2 && +value[0] === 0)) ev.target.value = value.slice(0, value.length - 1)
```

I need to validate the field in this way
12.3.3 not valid
10.2 valid
100.2 not valid

Comment: Regexp **alone** is not the right tool for this because doing things like making sure number is not more than 100 is complicated in regexp. Here's an example for INTEGER alone (only the max 100 rule, not the other rules) and this cannot handle floating points: `/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$/` basically check if it starts with anything from 1 to 9 followed by zero, one or two characters that is from 0 to 9. Yes, it is much harder to read than `value < 100`. For `value > 100` the regexp would be `/^(10[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3,}$/`

Answer (score 1):

The input type of number should theoretically not allow you input numbers that contain multiple radix characters (`.`). For your other two requirements, instead of using regex, it might simply be more intuitive and simpler to:

- evaluate as a string to ensure it doesn't exceed 6 characters, and
- evaluate as a number to ensure it doesn't exceed 100 in value

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
function isNumberValid(num) {
  // Restrict to max 6 digits
  if (num.replace(/[^0-9]/, '').length > 6) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // Cap value at 100
  if (+num > 100) {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  const isValid = isNumberValid(e.currentTarget.value);
  console.log(isValid);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" />100.10.1
```

Answer (score 1):

`^(\d{1}(?:\.\d{1,5})?|\d{2}(?:\.\d{1,4})?|100(?:\.0{1,3})?)$`

...validates:

- values in [0..100]
- single digit followed by up to 5 optional decimals
- two digits followed by up to 4 optional decimals
- 100 followed by up to 3 optional 0's

see: https://regex101.com/r/PWseLS/1